# Why does authorization fail when I commit to svn using VisualSVN?

Tags: svn

I have setup svnserve and for now now I am testing a repository with no credentials, so in svnserve.config I have

```
[general]
# anon-access = write
### auth-access = write

# use-sasl = false
```

And restarted the service

I have successfully got a working copy of a project on a seperate machine using VisualSVN and svn://server/repos however when I commit using VisualSVN I get authorization failed

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncomment the `anon-access = write` line; the default is read-only.

Comment: OMG what a doughnut!!! I'm new to svnserve and I thought that 1 # stood for a line to be read, DOH, LOL